# How to combine multiple resources into one feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, feed

How can we combine all these resources into one feed, with the most recent submission showing at the top?

**user.rb**

```ruby
  # Returns status feed.
  def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
    Habit.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
    Valuation.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
    Goal.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
    Quantified.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                     OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150311202504) do

  create_table "authentications", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "index"
    t.string   "create"
    t.string   "destroy"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "days", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "level_id"
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.boolean  "missed",     default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end

  create_table "goals", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "deadline"
    t.boolean  "accomplished"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "goals", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "goals", ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id"

  create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "left"
    t.integer  "level"
    t.text     "committed"
    t.datetime "date_started"
    t.string   "trigger"
    t.string   "target"
    t.string   "reward"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "habits", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "habits", ["user_id"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id"

  create_table "levels", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "habit_id"
    t.integer  "days_needed"
    t.boolean  "passed",      default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

  create_table "quantifieds", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "categories"
    t.string   "metric"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id"

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "relationships", ["followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_followed_id"
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
  add_index "relationships", ["follower_id"], name: "index_relationships_on_follower_id"

  create_table "results", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "result_value"
    t.date     "date_value"
    t.integer  "quantified_id"
    t.boolean  "good"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "missed_days"
    t.text     "missed_levels"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

  create_table "valuations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.boolean  "private_submit"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "valuations", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "valuations", ["user_id"], name: "index_valuations_on_user_id"

end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```html
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if logged_in?
     @habits = current_user.habits.build
     @valuations = current_user.valuations.build
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
      @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
      @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
     @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
   end
   end


  def about 
 end
end
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**Thanks so much for your time!** So far Infused's answer isn't working.

Comment: To get the desired result, you may need to create a separate "activity" model to aggregate all the data into a single table that you can easily query. Check out [RailsCasts #407](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch) for a walkthrough.

Comment: I'd use a view-backed model [(read about it here)](http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-11-view-backed-models/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle it is to combine the collections with `+`:

```
cond = ["user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id]

Habit.where(cond) + Valuation.where(cond) + Goal.where(cond) + Quantified.where(cond)
```

As [Matt Brictson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4625365/matt-brictson) mentioned in a comment, there may be a better way to aggregate the various models, but simply using `+` to join the collections will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Infused! I added your code to `def feed end` and got this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PagesController#home SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: : SELECT "habits".* FROM "habits" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1). You have any idea where we went wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the `habits` table does not have a `user_id` column.

Comment: If I remove `Habit` then it also occurs for `Valuation` and so on and so forth. They all have `user_id` infused.

Comment: Well, that's the only column referenced in your query, so no idea what else it could be.

Comment: def feed
    cond = ["user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id]
    Valuation.where(cond) + Goal.where(cond) + Quantified.where(cond)
  end gives ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PagesController#home SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: : SELECT "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1)

Comment: Are you able to run `SELECT "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1)` from the sqlite console?  If not, you definitely have a problem with your table.

Comment: Hmmm I get this: Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.rc3)
2.1.3 :001 > SELECT "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1)
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
...ions".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id ...
...                               ^
 from /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
 from /Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-.........etc which is weird because it works when I put back the original code in the question.

Comment: Use the sqlite console, not the rails console.

Comment: Ohhh damn I cant figure out how to open it. I tried this: nthony-Gallis-MacBook-Pro:pecoce galli01anthony$ sqlite3 data.db
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1)
   ...>
   ...>
   ...>

Comment: Use `sqlite3 data.db`. Then once you are in the console paste: `SELECT "valuations".* FROM "valuations" WHERE (user_id IN ([]) OR user_id = 1);`. You can also enter `.fullschema` to see the table and column definitions.

Comment: I got: `Error: no such table: valuations` but there is clearly a table in my schema, Infused (added schema above). Unfortunately running `rake db:reset` didn't help either.